# Unable to generate help files from R package

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools

I have created a package in R. It is all fully documented and written according to R package guidelines. I have used devtools to generate documentation.

```
document("/home/rstudio/EndoMineR/")
```

However when I try to use `?EndoMineR` I get the error:

```
No documentation for ‘EndoMineR’ in specified packages and libraries:
you could try ‘??EndoMineR’
```

How can I create the help files for my package? What am I likely to be missing?

As additional information, when I click the package name in R studio I get the help files but not if I try `?EndoMineR`. Also the `.Rd` files in the man directory (which I think is what `devtools::document()` generates) seem to be updating just fine. I assume the `?EndoMiner` accesses the man files so I'm not sure why this folder is not accessible (it is top level)

Comment: Did you run "Install and restart" after generating the docs?

Comment: Yes I did many times.

Comment: And do you have an .Rd file with alias "EndoMineR"?